# What is the hash/number sign in a .NET / PowerShell type and can it be used in scripting?

Tags: .net, powershell

I was writing a simple PowerShell script when I noticed in an exception that PowerShell seems to know more about an object than just its .NET type.

Here is an example:

```
[int] (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='wscsvc'")
```

So this statement is wrong: obviously `Get-CimInstance` does not return an int. What is interesting in the exception I get:

```
Cannot convert the "Win32_Service: Security Center (Name = "wscsvc")" value of
type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/cimv2/Win32_Service"
to type "System.Int32".
At line:1 char:1
+ [int] (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='wscsvc'")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Where does `#root/cimv2/Win32_Service` come from? Is that a valid way of declaring a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#root/cimv2/Win32_Service` is the local part of the "management path" used for the WMI operation you requested. (The full path for the Win32_service class would include the host name: `\\host\root/cim2/Win32_service`). The type, `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/cimv2/Win32_Service`, is used internally by Powershell to adapt WMI's object model to Powershell's object model.

While the # syntax can't be used, you can use a WMI management paths in various Powershell WMI operations.

So the answer to your question is technically no, but practically yes. As a proof point, Jaykul's WMI explorer - written in PS - uses the WMI path syntax quite a bit.

Note also, that the management path is further extended to specify a WMI instance. Here's a [pointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementpath(v=vs.110).aspx) into MSDN on one of the relevant topics.

Answer (score 1):

`root/cimv2` is the default [namespace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198933.aspx) for WMI queries which is automatically used when you don't explicitly specify a namespace. So `root/cimv2/Win32_Service` is the path to the class you requested.